# How to solve java.io.IOException: Stream closed error

Tags: java, hibernate

I used RequestDispatcher to forward to signIn.jsp but it gives me error. not able to find the error and error be like javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Here what it did the coding

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import com.hibernate.utils.HibernateUtils;
import com.lottery.classes.User;

SessionFactory sfactory = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sfactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
tx.commit();
session.close();
sfactory.close();
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("signIn.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

what it expected and what i get
i expected to open signIn.jsp page but giving me error stream closed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.